# My X_App is in playstore, How will i get to know which user has installed my app and which user has uninstalled my app in android

Tags: java, android

I have deployed my X_App into play store and i want to know which user has installed my app and which user has uninstalled my app in android?
Can someone please help me in this. I want to track the user who has uninstalled my app and uninstall count in android?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Google console has all these information look your console

Comment: see your google play developer console in this you can see that current install and total install.use google analytics to track users

Comment: does not seem like a question for #java tag.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't point to a particular user who has either installed or un-installed your app, you could get your daily installed/un-installed statistics in the following category - 

**Android Version**
**Device**
**Tablets**
**Country**
**Language**
**App version**
**Carrier**

from the google play dev console.

***If you need further insights into your uninstalls you could take a look at this site - https://www.uninstall.io/***

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty more ways of tracking uninstalls. You can run a ping service from the device to the server periodically. You can also send blank notifications intermittently to make sure the app is still on the device. You can ignore rendering these notifications to your users.

If you are looking for a tool that does app engagement and analytics then you can check out clevertap.com They provide uninstall tracking right out of the box.

If you were looking for a pure technical explanation of how GCM and Apple track uninstalls then you can read about it here. Track App Uninstalls effectively (https://blog.clevertap.com/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/) I have also covered alternative methods if you wanted to implement the uninstall tracking yourself!

Good luck.